# Replacing UTF-8 KeyCap Digit Character in PHP

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I am trying to replace these [0️⃣1️⃣2️⃣2️⃣3️⃣4️⃣5️⃣6️⃣7️⃣8️⃣9️⃣] UTF characters from a string. But somehow all other digit characters are also getting replaced.
I've tried using replacing by range.
Here is what i've tried

```
$post = '  ️7️⃣8️⃣6️⃣️  ';

$post = preg_replace('/[\x{0030}-\x{0040}]/u', '', $post);

echo $post;
```

How to do it

Comment: Try `preg_replace('/[0-9]\x{FE0F}\x{20E3}|\x{D83D}\x{DD1F}/u', '', $post)`

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: Its replacing all the characters in my string. However it works when i check on regex101 website. Strange :(

Comment: Can you please share a test case via https://3v4l.org/? See https://3v4l.org/uP4Ss

Comment: Try also `preg_replace('/[0-9]\p{M}+/u', '', $post)`

Comment: I have turned on error reporting this is coming : Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: disallowed Unicode code point (>= 0xd800 && <= 0xdfff) at offset 29 in ---check2.php on line 72

Comment: That is warning, not an error. Does `preg_replace('/[0-9]\p{M}+/u', '', $post)` work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes this one is working. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61826657/3832970), please consider accepting/upvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may remove all those digits that have diacritic marks after them (all those numbers you shared are actually digits with some diacritics after):

```
preg_replace('/[0-9]\p{M}+/u', '', $post)
```

The `[0-9]` will match ASCII digits from `0` to `9`, and the `\p{M}+` matches 1 or more diacritic marks. So, regular ASCII digits will not be removed.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mGozX9/1)

Comment: The UTF-8 character  is not removed with this regex.

Comment: Solved my issue. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what result you need.

The key's one to nine are combinations how "5\u{fe0f}\u{20e3}". Key Ten is the unicode symbol "\u{1f51f}". If only these symbols are to be removed, you must do this:

```
$post = '123️0️⃣1️⃣2️⃣2️⃣3️⃣abc4️⃣x8x5️⃣6️⃣7️⃣8️⃣9️⃣️56';

$post = preg_replace('~[0-9]\x{fe0f}\x{20e3}|\x{1f51f}~u', '', $post);

echo $post;
```

Output:

```
123️abcx8x️56
```